# Передача значений из QBarSet в QDoubleSpinBox используя PyQt5

Tags: python, pyqt5, gui, pyqt, qdoublespinbox

При нажатии на столбец нужно вывести его индекс в `QDoubleSpinBox` для данного примера

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Form implementation generated from reading ui file 'untitled.ui'
#
# Created by: PyQt5 UI code generator 5.13.1
#
# WARNING! All changes made in this file will be lost!
import sys, random
from PyQt5.Qt import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPainter
from PyQt5.QtChart import *
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_Form(object):
    def setupUi(self, Form):
        Form.setObjectName("Form")
        Form.resize(1166, 803)
        self.verticalLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(Form)
        self.verticalLayout_2.setObjectName("verticalLayout_2")
        #----------------------------------------


        self.chart = QChart()
        self.chart.addSeries(self.append_series())
        self.chartView = QChartView(self.chart)
        self.verticalLayout_2.addWidget(self.chartView)

        self.doubleSpinBox = QtWidgets.QDoubleSpinBox()
        self.doubleSpinBox.setObjectName("doubleSpinBox")
        self.verticalLayout_2.addWidget(self.doubleSpinBox)

        self.retranslateUi(Form)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Form)

        self.timer = QTimer()
        self.timer.setInterval(1000)
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.new_series)
        self.timer.start()

    def append_series(self):
        set0 = QBarSet("Min")
        set1 = QBarSet("Mid")
        set2 = QBarSet("Max")

        set0.append([random.randint(1, 4) for i in range(10)])
        series = QStackedBarSeries()
        series.clicked.connect(self._on_click_series)

        series.append(set0)
        series.setBarWidth(1)

        return series
    def _on_click_series(self, index, bar_set):
        print(index, bar_set.label())


    def new_series(self):
        self.chart.removeAllSeries()
        self.chart.addSeries(self.append_series())

    def retranslateUi(self, Form):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Form.setWindowTitle(_translate("Form", "Form"))



if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    Form = QtWidgets.QWidget()
    ui = Ui_Form()
    ui.setupUi(Form)
    Form.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> value : double
>
> Это свойство содержит значение spin box.
>
> **setValue(double val)** будет генерировать valueChanged(), если новое значение отличается от старого.

```
import sys, random
from PyQt5.Qt import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPainter
from PyQt5.QtChart import *
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_Form(object):
    def setupUi(self, Form):
        Form.setObjectName("Form")
        Form.resize(1166, 803)
        self.verticalLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(Form)
        self.verticalLayout_2.setObjectName("verticalLayout_2")
        #----------------------------------------
        self.chart = QChart()
        self.chart.addSeries(self.append_series())
        self.chartView = QChartView(self.chart)
        self.verticalLayout_2.addWidget(self.chartView)
        self.doubleSpinBox = QtWidgets.QDoubleSpinBox()
        self.doubleSpinBox.setObjectName("doubleSpinBox")
        self.verticalLayout_2.addWidget(self.doubleSpinBox)
        self.retranslateUi(Form)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Form)
        self.timer = QTimer()
        self.timer.setInterval(1000)
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.new_series)
        self.timer.start()

    def append_series(self):
        set0 = QBarSet("Min")
        set1 = QBarSet("Mid")
        set2 = QBarSet("Max")
        set0.append([random.randint(1, 4) for i in range(10)])
        series = QStackedBarSeries()
        series.clicked.connect(self._on_click_series)
        series.append(set0)
        series.setBarWidth(1)
        return series
        
    def _on_click_series(self, index, bar_set):
        print(index, bar_set.label())
        self.doubleSpinBox.setValue(index)                              # <---

    def new_series(self):
        self.chart.removeAllSeries()
        self.chart.addSeries(self.append_series())

    def retranslateUi(self, Form):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Form.setWindowTitle(_translate("Form", "Form"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    Form = QtWidgets.QWidget()
    ui = Ui_Form()
    ui.setupUi(Form)
    Form.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]